# Querying array using list in postgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a table in postgre SQL like this
which using 1 dimentional integer data type in `array` column

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id |  name  |   array   |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | apple  | {1, 2, 3} |
|  2 | mango  | {2, 3, 4} |
|  3 | banana | {4, 5, 6} |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

and I want to do a query to find every rows with `array` column contains at least one number from my list of number.  For example, search each array to see if it contains `2, 4`

Is there any better solution than using query like this?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 2 = ANY (array) OR 4 = ANY (array)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE '{1,4}' && array
```